# connect() within render()?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've got a dynamic list of properties that I'm attempting to use to instantiate a React component for each object in that list.

Here's a simplified version of my `mapStateToProps()` and `mapDispatchToProps()`:

```
export function mapStateToProps(id) {
  return function(state) {
    return state.widgets.find((widget) => id === widget.id);
  };
}

export function mapDispatchToProps(id) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return {
      fetchData: (path, props) => dispatch(fetchData(id, path, props)),
    };
  }; 
};
```

Then in the parent component:

```
render() {

  const widgets = this.props.widgets.map((widget) => {
    return connect(
      mapStateToProps(id),
      mapDispatchToProps(id),
    )(Widget);
  });

  return <div>{ widgets }</div>;
}
```

It doesn't throw any exceptions, but it doesn't call `mapStateToProps()` or `mapDispatchToProps()`.

My only guess so far is that `connect()` needs to be called earlier, but I'm not sure how to do that with a dynamic list of props. Anyone have any thoughts on how to make this work?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? why are you not passing the props you get via `props.widgets` to a bunch of `Widget` components? .e.g `return <div>{this.props.widgets.map(w => <Widget ...w>)}</div>`

Comment: The widget components are set up as [container components](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html), because they dispatch actions and trigger state updates. I can see how your suggestion would work to replace `mapStateToProps`, but how would it work for `mapDispatchToProps`?

Comment: I agree with @thedude, you can bind `fetchData` to the parent component and just pass the function as a property to each component `<Widget fetchData={this.props.fetchData} />`, Done!! No need to use connect inside the `render` method.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'll try that and follow up shortly. But in the meantime - why can't/shouldn't I use `connect` inside of `render`?

Comment: The answer that question is the same as "Would you ever write `class NewComponent extends Component { render() { .. } }` inside `render`? `connect` returns a component, so while strictly speaking, it can be called in `render` is should only be used in a place that is expecting a component definition.. not where a component is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` have a second argument of `ownProps`. You can grab the passed props in those functions and export your connected Widget like you would any other container.

```
// WidgetContainer.js

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return state.widgets.find((widget) => ownProps.id === widget.id);
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {   
  return {
    fetchData: (path, props) => dispatch(fetchData(ownProps.id, path, props)),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Widget);
```

Then in your loop do what @thedude is suggesting:

```
return <div>{this.props.widgets.map(w => <Widget id={w.id} />)}</div>
```

docs: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use connect inside the render method. Instead, use the props to send whatever you need to the children.

```
@connect(state => ({
  widgets: state.yourReducer.widgets
}), {
  fetchData: yourFetchActionCreator, // <-- bind your action creator here
})
class ParentComponent extends PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {
        this.props.widgets.map(widget =>
          <Widget {...widget} fetchData={this.props.fetchData} />)
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Inside `Widget` you will have the ID and everything that's inside each `widget` object.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand your solution, but I'm curious - why doesn't connect work inside of render?